# Resources missing C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources

I was adding some images to buttons and when i complied then suddenly errors started to appear on all buttons that were previously working fine

error is at this line

```
this.buttonJobCard.Image = global::Management_Studio.Properties.Resources.car;
```

above line was added by VS and now if i erase resources and place a dot after properties then only settings appear in intelisense
have any idea what might be wrong

Comment: What's the error message that you're receiving?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Resources' does not exist in the namespace 'Management_Studio.Properties' (are you missing an assembly reference?) E:\Afnan\Projects\Auto Master\New\Management Studio\Management Studio\Login.Designer.cs 91 75 Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few times I also face this problem in VS2010.
To resolve this issue remove error line code (image line code) and readd the image with button or control from whitch earlier associated.

Answer (score -1):

There is something wrong. You made a mistake unintentionally and one error stopped your program running. For example me, saved a picture with same name again and used for a button.

After warning from c#, my program down!! But I didn't understand what happened.after 3 or 4 hours search I found out  was an error in `Resources.resx` section of my program.after deleted a couple of line belong to error -my mistake about name of picture- in code of `Resources.resx` error was gone and my program run!